# mutually referential classes yield "incomplete type" error

Tags: c++, class, oop, scope, g++

I have a situation in which A has a reference to a class C defined inside B, and C has an instance of class B.

When I try to compile the code below, I get "`field a has incomplete type`". I assume this is because the compiler does not know how much memory it should allocate for an instance of A.

```
class A;

class B {
public:
  class C {
    A a;
  };
};

class A {
  A(const B::C& _c) 
    : c(_c)
  {}
  const B::C& c;
};
```

But when I try to compile this, I get "`C in class B does not name a type`":

```
class B;
class B::C;

class A {
  A(const B::C& _c) 
    : c(_c)
  {}
  const B::C& c;
};


class B {      
public:
  class C {
    A a;
  };
};
```

How can I convince the compiler that `B::C` is a real type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an absolute guess, I notice there's one permutation you haven't tried:

```
class B {
public:
  class C; // Forward declaration
};

class A {
  A(const B::C& _c) 
    : c(_c)
  {}
  const B::C& c;
};

class B::C {
  A a;
  C() : a(*this) {}    // Thanks Nim for pointing this out!
};
```

This is quite possibly illegal, but worth a shot I think.  If it doesn't work, then I don't see any way around the problem.

Comment: I don't believe this will compile, the default constructor for A doesn't initialize the reference to C. However, to get the above to work, all you need is the constructor for C to initialize A with itself - but you have two different instances of A, perhaps that is that is what you required? (@j_random_hacker, apologies if you implied this in your answer!)

Comment: @Nim: Thinking about it, you're right.  Updated.  (Though technically the problem is that `A` does not have a default ctor, because a user-defined ctor was given -- not that it has a faulty default ctor that fails to initialise `c`.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Even if you defined a default constructor, you'd somehow have to initialise the reference to C. I can think of one way where you can have a reference member in your class, but if default constructed, not to have that reference... use boost::variant<int, const B::C&> c, rather than raw const B::C& c. Using the variant allows you to also test to see if there is a valid reference before using it... if interested, I'll post the full code as a full answer below...

Comment: @Nim: Yes, that would be another way to solve it. Though I personally prefer to just avoid having a default ctor if reference members exist -- that way you know that it's always initialised.  If I want something similar that can be initialised or not, I'll use a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The forward declaration for `A` doesn't serve a purpose: you can't declare an instance of an incomplete type.

As to `B::C`, I don't think you can use nested names in an incomplete type. Just don't nest `C` in `B`: as far as I know this doesn't give you any significant advantages* and stops you from forward declaring it.

*The only advantage I can think of is that you can define it in the private section, but then `A` would have no business with it in the first place.

Comment: I can do that if I have to, but in the code I'm writing it makes more sense to have C be nested in B. Is there a good reason C++ doesn't allow me to declare nested incomplete types? Or is this just a quirk of the language?

Comment: @Andrew: It appears that you can do this (see j_random_hacker's answer). Whether the complication is worth it... I guess another reason to nest types is to get class names decorated - however, a namespace is a dedicated tool for that.